# Has the shortcut for the Annotation Tool's eraser function been changed?

Tags: grease-pencil, annotation

Previously, D+RMB would bring up the eraser tool, and rotating the mouse wheel in this state would resize the eraser.
But in 4.0 this does not work
What is the current shortcut? And is there any way to change it back?

[image]

EDITED
The keymap was there
But scaling the eraser range with the mouse wheel does not work
[image]

Comment: I can only confirm what @JohnEason wrote in his answer, the shortcut has not been changed - it still works for me and I've certainly not changed it to make it work like before since I hardly use annotations at all. Maybe there was a change made by accident? Maybe you have some third-party addons that need this shortcut and changed it? To change it back see his answer, to see if it is now attached to something else try switching the _Keymap_ search from _Name_ to _Key-Binding_ and start typing "d right" to see if or what results come up.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thank you
It appears to be set up the same as his
But the problem is still unresolved
Edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender 4.02 uses the same shortcut as version 3 here (D-RMB).
I've not tried changing it, but type 'gpencil.annotate' into the search field of <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keymap</kbd> and the last entry under <kbd>Grease Pencil</kbd> seems to be the correct shortcut.

[image]

Comment: I checked and it looks like my preferences are set the same as yours

Comment: I've no idea in that case I'm afraid. As @GordonBrinkmann says it might be a third-party addon, or possible something external to Blender that has hijacked that key combination.

Comment: @Jhn Eason I found the cause
It seems the importer add-on called "Drag & Drop" was the cause
Thank you very much

Comment: Ah ok. It's always worth temporarily disabling external addons if you get unexpected results.